# How to correct the color of one image based on another image in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, print-design

I have an image that I want to adjust in GIMP to make it look like a target image which is approved for printing. I'm just not sure how to get from the source image to the target with GIMP.

Source:

[image]

[image] [image]

Target:

[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

There's no practical method to calculate the operations automatically, if you want only global adjustments with no masks or selections. The only way is to guess and retry. Here's one such attempt.

The source and target are interleaved by inserting a striped layer mask to see both images side by side in different areas of the image. Good processing of the source will cause the borders to fade.

[image]

Guess 1: it needs a contrast boost to the darker half of the brightness scale. Curves can do this. Of course, the brighter half will become flatter as a consequence:

[image]

The 2nd guess is to increase the saturation of the sky. GIMP's basic installation doesn't have a properly adjustable color range Hue&Saturation&Lightness tool like Photoshop. I made a coarse selection of the sky as a workaround:

[image]

Your target has some local contrast boost. Photoshop users have quite a good tool in the Camera Raw filter set, but such "clarity" filters are for sale as plugins for those who want one click results. Something resembling this in GIMP can be achieved by sharpening in the old school way - that's Unsharp Mask:

[image]

It's now closer than the source was, but it's not exact. I checked in Photoshop that your target can be printed in CMYK without radical color changes. My version is so close to your "target" that I believe it's also printable, but nothing guarantees that another RGB image after the same treatment I gave is also printable in CMYK.

**NOTE1 a radical update**
Mr. Billy Kerr has told in his comment that GIMP can show the result if one converts his RGB image to a known CMYK print process color profile like Euroscale.Coated.icc or other. I tried it and it really works in current GIMP. So: Claims that GIMP knows nothing of CMYK printing is today proven to be false.

One must download the wanted color profile and set it to be used as the proof color profile and activate Proof colors. As said, the actual conversion of the file to CMYK colors must be done elsewhere (=Krita, Photoshop or other CMYK supporting program), but in GIMP one can follow in real time how his future CMYK version develops as he makes edits to his RGB image. In gamut warming mode GIMP even points which areas cannot be printed.

Comment: +! - but just a little note here, Krita supports conversion to CMYK mode. So, all is not lost if you can't afford Photoshop.

Comment: True. Actually Krita understands  also CMYK print process color profiles and making adjustments in CMYK mode.

Comment: Also, just in case the OP simply wants to print a photo, conversion to CMYK is not actually always desirable. Most home/office printers can't print CMYK images, and most online photo printing services expect RGB files.  CMYK is certainly needed for print processes that use separations, such as offset lithography.

Comment: Seeing a plausible prediction of the printed result needs some knowledge of the print process. An online print service may show a preview or support a color profile. Or it tells nothing and they print what they happen to print.

Comment: Note that GIMP does actually support colour management and a soft proofing preview of CMYK colours based on choosing an ICC CMYK colour profile, but it doesn't support actual CMYK mode. So you can at least see what an RGB image will look like if printed in CMYK. ICC colour profiles can be downloaded for free from the ICC website: https://color.org/profiles2.xalter

Comment: @BillyKerr It's actually for industrial printing. I'm wondering is it possible the difference between the source and goal images be because an ICC profile is applied to the image?